# ADF use API to create or update Key vault secret

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my ADF pipeline, I need to add a new version of the secret in the key vault.  However, I get the following error when I do.

```
Details
{"error":{"code":"BadParameter","message":"Property value has invalid value\r\n"}}
```

I can't grasp wheat the error is about.
using Web activity with PUT method to the URL

```
'https://dmkeyvault1.vault.azure.net//secrets/SecretName?api-version=7.4'
```

Using Method `PUT` and the body is

```
{
    "value":"{"Item1":"Item1Value","Item2":"Item2Value"}"
}
```

I know the problem is with the format of the value in the 'Body'
But don't know how to fix it.
If I have just a simple string

```
{
    "value":"MyValue"
}
```

instead of json formatted, it will work just fine.

Comment: Could you please try removing the quotes  : 
`{
    "value":"{Item1:Item1Value,Item2:Item2Value}"
}`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/update-secret/update-secret?view=rest-keyvault-secrets-7.4&tabs=HTTP#secretbundle),

> You cannot pass a JSON as secret value from this REST API, so pass it as JSON string and whenever you are using the secret value from this, convert it back to JSON and use as per your requirement.

To do that pass the body like below with `PUT` request.

```
{

"value":"{\"Item1\":\"Item1Value\",\"Item2\":\"Item2Value\"}",
"contentType":"",
"attributes":{
"enabled":true
},
"tags":{
}
}
```

[image]

Also, when updating the secret value to a new version, you need to pass the old secret version in the `PUT` url like below.

```
{vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secret-name}/{secret-version}?api-version=7.4
```

To get that use a web activity before this with a `GET` request and use the below URL.

```
https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<secret_name>/?api-version=7.0
```

It will give its URL in the `id` of the activity output.

[image]

Use this id and build the new URL with below expression.

```
@concat(activity('Web2').output.id,'?api-version=7.4')
```

Now, debug the pipeline and it will update the secret value like below.

[image]

**Secret updated in keyvault:**

[image]